# Inequality for a concave function

Tags: functions

I am trying to solve a problem showing that $f(1)+f(-1) \leq \int_{-1}^{1}f(x)$ is true for any concave function on $[-1,1]$. Obviously, when we plug in a concave function, (such as $f(x) = \sqrt{x+1}$), its true, but I'm not sure how to prove that for *any* concave function. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: For $x \in [-1,1], x = (1+x)/2 \cdot 1 + (1-x)/2\cdot -1.$

Comment: your example sqrt(x) is not defined on the interval (-1,1).

Comment: Hint 2: [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality)

Comment: @stochasticboy321 thank you for the hint! I've been messing around with this but I'm not sure where to use it. Do you mind sharing if it's used in the integral?

Comment: By concavity, for every $x \in [-1,1],$ $f(x) \ge \frac{1+x}{2} f(1) + \frac{1-x}{2} f(-1)$. So, $\int_{[-1,1]} f(x) \ge \int_{[-1,1]} \cdots$. This is just a slightly different way of writing Arthur's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because $f(-1) + f(1)$ is equal to the integral of the linear function that goes from $(-1, f(-1))$ to $(1, f(1))$, and the concave function, by definition, lies on or above this line.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. What I'm still confused about is how $f(-1) + f(1)$ is equal to the integral of the linear function. Wouldn't that be $f(-1)-f(1)$ instead?

Comment: @SummerHartley Take a very simple case, like $f(-1)=f(1)=1$ to see that your suggestion does not work. To prove that mine works, either see that the region is trapezoid-shaped (make sure you be careful with negative areas), or simply find the $ax+b$ expression for the linear function and integrate it.